# Changing Sound's path in NI Massive

Tags: vst

Can anyone tell how to change NI Massive's "Documents/Native Instruments/Massive" location on Mac (the one in Options > Browser)? I can add a new folder and delete it but I can't do that with the primary one..

Comment: Well I guess you just can't.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Add" and "Delete" buttons to the right of the "User Library Directories" window to manage the directories included in the database.  If you change the paths with these buttons then don't forget to "Rebuild DB" button afterwards to rebuild the database and include the changes.  (All detailed in the User manual.)

Comment: I think the problem was more that he couldn't delete the default path

Comment: The manual infers (but does not explicitly say) that the default path can not be deleted.

Comment: @BitDepth the manual IMPLIES it. You then inferred the implication...